# About black holes paradox

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

About the information paradox in the black holes, isn't it possible in principle, that the "singularity" itself doesn't really exists, and its just the horizon plane, where the particles that falls into it gets stucked, and the hawking radiation, instead of being the creation of the 2 virtual particles, it would creates only the one that goes out of it, and that be entangled with a correspondent one stuck in the horizon, with that way we could retrieve the information, I'm sure that is some problems with that view, but, since we proved we can describe all the black hole just with the horizon itself, doesn't it shows that there isn't nothing more than the horizon?
I mean, for me its a much smaller leap, than what physics is doing to assume that since the black hole can be described by the horizon, our hole universe can be described in one less dimension.

Comment: The virtual particle picture of Hawking radiation is a simplification. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/30601/123208 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/252183/123208 Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17338/123208 and its Related questions.

Comment: The horizon *plane*?

Comment: yeah, like the horizon is a 2d sctructure, isn't it?

Comment: @Caio The event horizon (of a Schwarzschild black hole) is a spherical 2D surface. Calling it a plane is a bit confusing. A [rotating black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole) is more complicated.

Comment: Sorry, I misscalled it, but what I meant is that there isn't anything "inside" it, like it would be some kind of "bubble" in the fabric of space-time, it wouldn't exists the interior. Can this be possible?